# JS: How to get anchor values inside of a div with classname "contractor"

Tags: dom

I have a problem accessing this anchor in a div.

```
    <div class="contractor">
        <a title="Andrew" href="/humans/">Andrew</a>
    </div>
```

How do you complete this beginning? I need the title, the href and the Text inside.

```
var contr = document.getElementsByClassName('contractor');

console.log(contr);
```

I need plain JavaScript, no jQuery

Comment: Do you want all of them (in an HTMLCollection) or just one? If all of them  them then `document.querySelectorAll('.contractor a')` should work, if just one then `document.querySelector('.contractor a')` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the data you need from the anchor, you can do the following by using query selector:

```js
const anchor = document.querySelector(".contractor a");
const title = anchor.getAttribute("title");
const href = anchor.getAttribute("href");
const text = anchor.text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ParentNode` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode). If you're confident that the `contractor` div will only have an `HTMLAnchorElement` child, you could do the following:

```js
const contractors = document.getElementsByClassName(`contractor`);
const contractor = constractors[0];
const anchor = contractor.firstElementChild;

const title = anchor.title;
const href = anchor.href;
```

If there might be more than one child element under each `contractor` div, then you would instead use the `ParentNode.children` property instead of `firstElementChild`.